# String Calculator Kata Code in TDD style

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit

I have done the following kata in TDD style and would appreciate it if someone could review my code and my tests.

> **String Calculator**
>
> - Create a simple `String` calculator with a method `int Add(string numbers)`. The method can take 0, 1 or 2 numbers, and will return their sum (for an empty string it will return 0). For example "" or "1" or "1,2".
> - Start with the simplest test case of an empty string and move to 1 and two numbers
> - Remember to solve things as simply as possible so that you force yourself to write tests you did not think about.
> - Remember to refactor after each passing test.
> - Allow the `Add` method to handle an unknown amount of numbers.
>
>   Allow the `Add` method to handle new lines between numbers (instead
>     of commas). The following input is ok:  "1\n2,3" (will equal 6). The following input is NOT ok: "1,\n" (not need to prove it - just clarifying).
> - Support different delimiters to change a delimiter, the beginning of the string will contain a separate line that looks like this:
>     "//[delimiter]\n[numbers…]". For example, "//;\n1;2" should return three
>     where the default delimiter is ';'. The first line is optional. All existing scenarios should still be supported.
> - Calling `Add` with a negative number will throw an exception "negatives not allowed" - and the negative that was passed. If there are multiple negatives, show all of them in the exception message.

```
public class StringCalculator
    {
        public int AddNumbers(string args)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args))
            {
                return 0;
            }

            var delimeters = new List<char>()
                                    {
                                        '\n',','
                                    };

            if (args[0] == '/')
            {
                var customDelimeter = args[2];
                delimeters.Add(customDelimeter);
                args = args.Remove(0,
                                   3);

            }

            var numbers = args.ToCharArray().Where(x => !delimeters.Contains(x)).ToList();

            if (numbers.Any(x => x == '-'))
            {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder= new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0;
                     i < numbers.Count;
                     i++)
                {
                    if (numbers[i] == '-')
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append("-");
                        stringBuilder.Append(numbers[++i]);
                        stringBuilder.Append(", ");
                    }    
                }

                throw new Exception(string.Format("negatives {0} not allowed",stringBuilder.ToString()));
            }

            var sum = numbers.Sum(x => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(x));

            return sum;
        }
    }
```

Tests:

```
 [TestFixture]
    public class StringCalculatorTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void ShouldReturnZeroForEmptyString()
        {
            var sut = new StringCalculator();
            var result = sut.AddNumbers("");
            Assert.AreEqual(0,result);
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCase(1,"1")]
        [TestCase(2,"2")]
        public void ShouldReturnNumberIfGivenOneNumber(int expected,string arg)
        {
            var sut = new StringCalculator();
            var result = sut.AddNumbers(arg);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected,result);
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCase(3, "1,2")]
        [TestCase(11, "1,2,3,5")]
        public void ShouldReturnSumOfAllNumbers(int expected, string arg)
        {
            var sut = new StringCalculator();
            var result = sut.AddNumbers(arg);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCase(3, "1\n2")]
        [TestCase(11, "1,2\n3,5")]
        public void ShouldAllowNewLineAsASeparator(int expected, string arg)
        {
            var sut = new StringCalculator();
            var result = sut.AddNumbers(arg);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCase(3, "//;\n1;2")]
        [TestCase(11, "//.\n1.2\n3.5")]
        [TestCase(11, "//-\n1-2\n3-5")]
        public void ShouldSupportDifferentSeparators(int expected, string arg)
        {
            var sut = new StringCalculator();
            var result = sut.AddNumbers(arg);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCase(3, "//;\n-1;2")]
        [TestCase(3, "//;\n-1;-2")]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
        public void ShouldThrowExceptionIfNegativeInArgs(int expected, string arg)
        {
            var sut = new StringCalculator();
            var result = sut.AddNumbers(arg);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, the signature should be `int Add(string numbers)` ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Single responsibility principle**

The method `AddNumbers()` violates the SRP because it is

- parsing arguments
- composing exception messages
- adding the numbers

this should be done in separate methods like

```
private bool ContainsCustomDelimiter(string argument)
private string GetCustomDelemiter(string argument)
private string ComposeExceptionMessage(IEnumerable<char> numbers)
```

by splitting this method into smaller methods which have a defined responsibility your code will be easier to maintain and extend.

---

**Number or digit ?**

Thats the question which bothers me the most. I think of numbers like 1, 3, 12, 56 but it looks like the method will only sum separated digits which should be clearly stated inside a documentation.

---

**Tests**

The testname `ShouldReturnZeroForEmptyString()` is misleading or the `AddNumbers()` method does not return the expected result.

> The method can take 0, 1 or 2 numbers, and will return their sum (for
>   an empty string it will return 0) for example “” or “1” or “1,2”

But an empty string **is not** a **null string**, nevertheless the `AddNumbers()` method is returning `0` for a null value also because of

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(args))
```

In my opinion the `AddNumbers()` method should throw an `NullReferenceException` for the case that the passed in string is `null`.

So you better check for

```
if (args.Length == 0) { return 0; }
```

which will throw the NRE if `args` is `null`

But there is another big problem. Assume you pass one of the following strings to the `AddNumbers()` method:

- "/"  -> throws IndexOutOfRange
- "//"  -> throws IndexOutOfRange

You need to always check for such edge cases, thats what tests are for.

---

Now let us talk about cases where the input is **not valid**.

What should happen for a given string like **"1, 2,3"** or **"1,2,A"** ? The first will return **5** and the second will return **5** too.

So you should better check `numbers` if they contain any non digit and handle this case.

---

**Naming**

Naming is important because it tells you (if done correctly) at first glance what a variable is about. **Bob the maintainer**  will have a hard time if he/she sees a variable named `sut` (but only if he/she doesn't know (like me) that sut stands for "system under test"). But nevertheless why don't you name it `calculator` ?

Comment: I feel like you're already aware of this but SUT is an acronym for System Under Test, a common term in unit testing. That said, I would also prefer for it to be called `calculator`.

Comment: I haven't been aware of this. These acronyms these days are driving me crazy ;-) Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 6):

Some things that come to mind are:

- Substitute `var numbers = args.ToCharArray().Where(x => !delimeters.Contains(x)).ToList();` with `var numbers = args.Where(x => !delimeters.Contains(x));` unless you specifically want a list. The `ToCharArray()` call should be superfluous.
- Substitute `if (numbers.Any(x => x == '-'))` with `if (numbers.Contains('-'))` for readability's sake.
- The command `stringBuilder.Append(numbers[++i]);` makes it so that `i` gets incremented twice in each cycle. Is it intentional? If not, you should remove the extra `++` and substitute it with `i + 1`.

Other than these, I don't see any problems in the code.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from what's already been said you should consider your test suite a bit more (I'm assuming you're using [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org) in pretty recent version).

**Apply [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) to the tests**

You have two more or less identical lines in all tests:

```
var sut = new StringCalculator();
var result = sut.AddNumbers(...);
```

Declare the calculator instance as a field in the fixture instead, and initialize in a `[SetUp]` method.

There's also the duplication of `var result = ...`. In this specific case I might go as far as to get rid of `result` entirely:

```
public void ShouldXxx(int expected,string arg)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, calculator.AddNumbers(arg));
}
```

While I'm at it this reads even better, IMHO:

```
public void ShouldXxx(int expected, string arg)
{
    Assert.That(calculator.AddNumbers(arg), Is.EqualTo(expected));
}
```

Try reading the code out loud for yourself for each of the samples above.

Further adding a few line breaks to the latest version makes it a bit easier to visually separate what you're testing from the expected result, but that's a very personal opinion. See refactored example below.

**Don't use SUT literally**

As others have already said, don't use `sut` as a variable name. Sure, you might know the context and be familiar with the acronym but I still consider `calculator.AddNumbers(...)` to be more expressive than `sut.AddNumbers()`.

One circumstance where you could use e.g. `sut` as a variable name is where you have a very generic test suite that can be reused for many implementations. However, even then I would strongly suggest that you name the variable referring to the SUT according to what kind of capabilities being tested within that specific suite. A short example:

```
public abstract class CloneableTests<T> where T: ICloneable
{
    private T cloneable; // Not 'sut'
    ....
}
```

**Remove unneeded attributes**

You don't need to use the `[TestFixture]` attribute. Marking individual methods with `[SetUp]` or one of the `[Test...]` attributes is sufficient. Also, using `[Test]` when `[TestCase]` is present is redundant.

Here's an excerpt from the refactored, and somewhat reformatted, tests:

```
public class StringCalculatorTests
{
    private StringCalculator calculator;

    [SetUp]
    public void InitFixture()
    {
        calculator = new StringCalculator();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldReturnZeroForEmptyString()
    {
        Assert.That(
            calculator.AddNumbers(String.Empty),
            Is.EqualTo(0)
        );
    }

    [TestCase(1, "1")]
    [TestCase(2, "2")]
    public void ShouldReturnNumberIfGivenOneNumber(int expected, string arg)
    {
        Assert.That(
            calculator.AddNumbers(arg),
            Is.EqualTo(expected)
        );
    }

    ...
}
```