# TDD: String Calculator Kata

Tags: python, strings, programming-challenge, regex, tdd

> [**String Calculator**](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/)
>
> 1. Create a simple String calculator with a method `int Add(string numbers)`.
>
>    1. The method can take 0, 1 or 2 numbers, and will return their sum (for an empty string it will return 0).
>         For example `""` or `"1"` or `"1,2"`.
>    2. Start with the simplest test case of an empty string and move to 1 and two numbers
>    3. Remember to solve things as simply as possible so that you force yourself to write tests you did not think about.
>    4. Remember to refactor after each passing test.
> 2. Allow the Add method to handle an unknown amount of numbers.
> 3. Allow the Add method to handle new lines between numbers (instead of commas).
>
>    1. The following input is ok: "1\n2,3" (will equal 6).
>    2. The following input is NOT ok: "1,\n" (not need to prove it - just clarifying).
> 4. Support different delimiters
>
>    1. to change a delimiter, the beginning of the string will contain a separate line that looks like this: "//[delimiter]\n[numbers…]".
>         For example, "//;\n1;2" should return three where the default delimiter is ';'.
>    2. The first line is optional. All existing scenarios should still be supported.
> 5. Calling Add with a negative number will throw an exception "negatives not allowed" - and the negative that was passed. If there are multiple negatives, show all of them in the exception message.

```
import re

def string_calculator(string):
    """
    Sums numbers in a string separated by delimiters.

    >>> string_calculator("")
    0
    >>> string_calculator("42")
    42
    >>> string_calculator("473,12")
    485
    >>> string_calculator("1\\n2,3")
    6
    >>> string_calculator("//;\\n1;2")
    3
    >>> string_calculator("-42, 2")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ValueError: negatives not allowed ['-42']
    >>> string_calculator("-42,31,-312")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ValueError: negatives not allowed ['-42', '-312']
    """
    if re.match('-[0-9]+', string):
        raise ValueError("negatives not allowed {}".format(
            re.findall('-[0-9]+', string)))
    separators = ',', '\\n'
    if "//" in string:
        sep_info = re.findall('//.+\n', string)[0]
        separators = sep_info.replace('//','').replace('\\n','')
        string = string.replace(sep_info, '')
    if not string:
        return 0
    if not any(separator in string for separator in separators):
        return int(string)
    return sum(int(number) for number in re.split('|'.join(separators), string))
```

Comment: *"If there are multiple negatives, show all of them in the exception message."* - you don't meet the whole of the spec, yet.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hops I had missed it! I ninja edited to fix it and added a test case.

Comment: Please consider: [For an iterative review, is it okay to edit my own question to include revised code?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c)

Answer (score 1):

There's a redundant `if` branch:

```
if not any(separator in string for separator in separators):
    return int(string)
```

removing it still passes all the tests, because

```
re.split('|'.join(separators), string)
```

returns a list containing the list itself if there are no separators in the string.